# Windows RT vs Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-rt

I'm new to programming for windows.
and I have one simple question for you, but it is unclear to me.

What is the different between Windows RT development of Windows 8 for tablets? (language c#)
Is it possible to write a single application - that will work in both systems?

If there is a link that read - will be happy.

Comment: Windows RT is an operating system with Modern UI. I think you mean WinRT which is the new runtime for Windows Store apps, available from both Windows RT and Windows 8 other editions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: if you're on C# it doesn't make a difference.

For a more elaborate explanation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631363/windows-rt-and-c-sharp).

Comment: Windows RT really does not impose any restrictions on the development?

Comment: Not as such. Some API is not available on Windows Phone, but that's a different matter from Windows RT, which can also be run on Microsoft Surface and other ARM devices. These functions are annotated accordingly in their MSDN documentation.

Comment: Please, edit your comment, because my question about Win 8 and Win RT (not WP).

Comment: I just wanted to add this for completeness. Otherwise, as I mentioned already, Windows 8 and Windows RT are the same when it comes to the C# API and development.