# Run Windows RT based app on Surface Pro 2 & Surface Pro 3 devices

Tags: windows-runtime

I am developing a Windows RT based application, I recently heard that Microsoft has launched Surface Pro 2 and Pro3 based devices seems it has Core i3, i5, i7 processor(not ARM Processor).

I am just curious that my app which is Windows RT based application will work on Surface Pro 2 or not?  Or will have to prepare separate build from visual studio which target to 64bit based devices?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. No.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows RT and c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631363/windows-rt-and-c-sharp)

Comment: That's not a duplicate of that question. The other one is focused on C# while no specific language was mentioned in this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows RT is a version of Windows for ARM devices. Windows Runtime is the modern API for building Windows apps that can run on ARM, x86 and x64. If your app is .NET or HTML-based - you can create one build for all platforms. If you have any native code - when you create a store package you can choose which platforms should be targeted and a separate build will be run for each platform. In most cases if you use native code you can limit yourself to ARM and x86 builds since x64 processors can run x86 code. ARM and Intel based processors need separate versions of the code. If you only use managed or HTML code - that gets compiled into native code based on architecture-agnostic build that you submit to the store.

Comment: I think his question is more clearly stated as: "Do I have to compile my app for multiple processor types in order to run my app on a surface pro?".

Comment: The OP seems to be unaware of what Windows RT means and I believe my answer would have clarified that enough to help understand that Windows Runtime based app can run on all processor architectures, but I expanded to make it more clear when separate builds will be generated.

Comment: Thanks Filip for detail comments, its clear to me now.