# How to write programs for Windows RT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt

I am wondering what i would need to write some programs for Windows RT. I am going to get a Surface RT (the one with the ARM Chip) for some school stuff and small experiments, because my Laptop i usually use for school broke. So, what IDE, SDKs and whatever do i need to do that?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631363/windows-rt-and-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

It's me again, i have found the following on the [XDA-Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-develop-on-windows-rt-a-c-scratchpad.2112351/), which seems to be enough for me. I tried to write a store app, but that is a bit too much for my small brain.